# Missing data (NA)

Tags: r

I know that for means and standard deviations, we should use the na.rm = TRUE to ensure that missing data is excluded.

I was just wondering that in scatterplots/histograms/boxplots etc - does R automatically ignore missing data?

With other functions, such as the lm() does R automatically ignore missing data? Or is there a way to ensure this? I don't want to remove the NA from my data-set as they are generally item non-responses, so I was just wondering how I go about removing them on specific occasions?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: [This article](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-does-r-handle-missing-values/) might answer some of your questions.

Comment: Handling missing data is specific to the operation, and while those functions (and several others) use `na.rm=` as an argument for handling them, that is neither required nor universal. If a given function supports it, that ability will be in its individual documentation. For instance, `?hist` says nothing about `NA` values but happily discards them, as in `hist(mtcars$disp[1:100])`. `?boxplot`, on the other hand, references `na.action=` instead. If you have specific functions, I suggest you read their documentation first. If it does not work as advertised, then come back with failing code.